# Autocompletado de Direcciones de Google (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Buenos días CREO que tengo un error en el método `getAutocompletePredictions` ya que el error que sale en un toast al escribir en el autocomplete de la app sale `Error : status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}`. Todo lo saque de la librería oficial de android. No se cual podrá ser el error adjunto mi código y muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

```
public class PlaceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context  Context
     * @param resource Layout resource
     * @param bounds   Used to specify the search bounds
     * @param filter   Used to specify place types
     */
    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds,
                             AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(), mBounds, null);
            // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting place predictions: " + status
                        .toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");
            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getFullText(null)));
            }
            // Buffer release
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the entered constraint
                    mResultList = getPredictions(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // Results
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    class PlaceAutocomplete {

        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }


}
```

`

La actividad:

```
public class ConfirmActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "ConfirmActivity";
private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
private AutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteTextView;
private TextView mNameTextView;
private TextView mAddressTextView;
private TextView mIdTextView;
private TextView mPhoneTextView;
private TextView mWebTextView;
private TextView mAttTextView;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ConfirmActivity.this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
    mAutocompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id
            .autoCompleteTextView);
    mAutocompleteTextView.setThreshold(3);
    mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mAddressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    mIdTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_id);
    mPhoneTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    mWebTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    mAttTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att);
    mAutocompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
    mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
    mAutocompleteTextView.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
        = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
        placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
    }
};

private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
        = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                    places.getStatus().toString());
            return;
        }
        // Selecting the first object buffer.
        final Place place = places.get(0);
        CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();

        mNameTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getName() + ""));
        mAddressTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAddress() + ""));
        mIdTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getId() + ""));
        mPhoneTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getPhoneNumber() + ""));
        mWebTextView.setText(place.getWebsiteUri() + "");
        if (attributions != null) {
            mAttTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions.toString()));
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connected.");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
            + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                    connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
}
```

}

Y el layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ConfirmActivity">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:hint="Enter Place Here"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Selected Place:"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/place_id"
    android:autoLink="phone"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
    android:autoLink="web"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/att"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:autoLink="web"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/poweredBy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/att"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/truiton_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/poweredBy"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
   />
```

Comment: Solicionado estaba mal la clave api.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que presentas tiene dos causas principales:

1) Estas definiendo:

```
  <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />
```

debes usar:

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />
```

2) La API Key que usas debe ser valida y debe estar habilitada esta API en la consola

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="<API KEY VALIDA" />
```

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro